# How to start React App on Development machine as in specific environment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

We are using Microsoft Windows for both development and hosting.

npm version - 6.8.0

node version - 10.15.3

I would like to know how I can start my ReactApp locally on my development machine as in **Production** environment.

We have multiple environments at work such as Test, Staging, PreProd, Prod.... etc and we want to test the behaviour of the app without actual deployment to the target env.

We've got some logic statements in the source codes by using `process.env.NODE_ENV` to check the different environments.

I tried to update `package.json` **scripts** section as the following.  But, it doesn't work.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production react-scripts start",
    "start-prod2": "set NODE_ENV=production&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I tried both `start-prod` and `start-prod2` .  Even though it hosts the app successfully, it's always in **development** mode.  Please see the following screenshots:

```
npm run start-prod
```

[image]

```
npm run start-prod2
```

[image]

If I use `npm run build`, it generates the build with production env.  But it takes too much time to test.

Could you please guide me how I could simulate the various environment in my development machine?

P.S.  I'm just using the default create-react-app script set up and I don't have any custom webpack config file.

Complete package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-workout-diary",
  "version": "0.10.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "formik": "^1.5.7",
    "has-value": "^2.0.2",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.6.0",
    "react-delay": "^0.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "redux-saga-routines": "^3.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production react-scripts start",
    "start-prod2": "set NODE_ENV=production&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see differently? Have you got a webpack config file too?

Comment: I'm not using manual webpack config file.  I'm using create-react-app default configuration.  I expected to see the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` as "production".  But now, it's always "development"

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the NODE_ENV variable:

> You cannot override NODE_ENV manually. This prevents developers from
>   accidentally deploying a slow development build to production.

What you can do is to use different `.env` files:
From: [React documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> Files on the left have more priority than files on the right:
>
> ```
> npm start: .env.development.local, .env.development, .env.local, .env
> npm run build: .env.production.local, .env.production, .env.local, .env
> npm test: .env.test.local, .env.test, .env (note .env.local is missing)
> ```

Comment: Can you help me explain how exactly does the precedence work? I mean, If I create different PORT and URL for each environment in their respective env files, how does the precedence from left to right will play a role in it? I am unable to get through this properly even from the documentation.

Comment: @bubble-cord If you for example create a PORT=8080 in .env and then PORT=8181 in .env.local, when you run npm start, the PORT will be equal to 8181.
Basically, the files on the left will have priority and will override the variable declared in files on the right side